# What will happen to deprecated std features like mem_fun in boost

Tags: c++, boost

I saw many things which firstly in boost are standardized like shared_ptr, bind, functional etc..

In my current project a old compiler is being used and people before me extensively used boost::mem_fn . I just watch yesterday in cppcon that mem_fun will be deprecated in C++17 and I asked to myself can this be a problem in future for us.

My question is not just about mem_fun. What is the general approach of boost  when standard deprecates some of the features which are also existing in boost. Does boost discourages usage of those features too? Can they remove some of the features in new library version? Or boost does not care about those?

Comment: I'm not sure if his is the right place to ask such question.

Comment: OT: Can you provide a link to some place where `std::mem_fn` is said to become deprecated in C++17?

Comment: It all depends on the libraries you are using - Most boost libraries provide way of keep/marking deprecated/removing deprecated stuff using defines, so you should look at the documentation for the boost libraries you are using.

Comment: @Holt Thanks a lot for asking that, While looking for a link I find out mem_fun will be deprecated not mem_fn.

Comment: You'd be better off asking the boost community this question.   Technically, deprecation of a "feature" in the C++ standard would only affect boost features that are implemented using the standard-deprecated feature - and not drive feature removal, as the boost feature could be reimplemented in other ways.   The answer is therefore non-technical - i.e.  related to maintenance philosophy/policy followed by the boost community.

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir This is what I thought - Note that `std::mem_fun` is already deprecated since C++11 and will be **removed** in C++17.